# Admin panel not loading properly, after magento 2 upgraded

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-upgrade

I have recently upgraded Magento from 2.3 version to 2.4 version and it has been the upgraded, after upgrade the admin panel is breaking. Not loading properly. Can anyone please help me with solution.

Comment: Do you have browser console errors? If so, can you share them?

Answer (score 0):

run below command, You must need to add your admin locale.. like en_GB,en_AU

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
```

Comment: why specific local en_us can't we run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Sometime frontend and admin locale not same so it's better to add locale in command. first run command ... tell me output ..if works then we discuss later

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: run below commands added in new answer

Comment: what is your admin and frontend locale??

Answer (score 0):

execute below commands

```
php bin/magento main:enable

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento main:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run these commands in order:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:c
```